# Get last index of "buffered.end(0)"?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

The following code tells me how far a video has been loaded. The returned value is in percentage:

```js
//Tell JS what video to look for
v = document.getElementById("my-video-id");

//[...]Functions that triggers debuglog() every second at the right time[...]

function debuglog(){
loadedpercentage=v.buffered.end(0) / v.duration * 100;
//A.K.A
//Video s loaded content, in seconds
//Divided by:
//Total video time, in seconds
//Multiplied by 100.
console.log(loadedpercentage);//Returns loaded percentage! Eg: 5.382738332.
}
```

So, as you can see, this function will return the loaded percentage of the video so far everytime its getting triggered.

**There is just one problem:**

When the user pauses and plays the video, a new buffer is created, which means we can no longer use `v.buffered.end(0)`. We must now use `v.buffered.end(1)`.

I know, I can tell the play/pause actions, for example, to pass the new buffer-number to `buffered.end`. I was just wondering if it is possible to simply tell javascript to "use the last one", "use the last buffer". I am thinking about something like this, maybe?

```
v.buffered.end(this.lastbuffer);
```

What is the best way to address this issue?

Again, thanks a lot SO!

**== EDIT ==**

Big thanks to @Kaiido for the answer and explanation!

Heres how to get the last buffer available for `buffered.end`:

```
v = document.getElementById("video");//Your video ID
console.log(v.buffered.end(v.buffered.length-1));
```

The above code outputs the wanted value, in seconds, in the console.

Please see the approved answer under this post for further explanation on how to get the *real* loaded percentage.

Cheers :)

Comment: Basically, I want the last buffer available for `buffered.end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges/length) property on the [TimeRanges](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges) returned by [HTMLMediaElement.buffered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/buffered):

```js
vid.onseeked = e => {
  console.log(vid.buffered.length);
}
```

```css
video{height: 200px;margin-bottom:100vh}
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm.360p.webm"></video>
```

Just use it.

But note that what you are measuring here is not the percentage loaded *per se*. For this, you'd need to iterate over all the TimeRanges and get their length and then calculate the ratio this whole represents with regards to the total length:

```js
vid.onseeked = e => {
  const buffers = vid.buffered;
  let buffered = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i<buffers.length; i++) {
    buffered += buffers.end(i) - buffers.start(i);
  }
  console.log((buffered / vid.duration) * 100, '%');
}
```

```css
video{height: 200px;margin-bottom:100vh}
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm.360p.webm"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to think the following will work. Let me know.

```js
//<!CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
var doc, bod, I; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var vid = I('vid'), prog = I('prog'), loaded = I('loaded'), progI;
vid.onloadedmetadata = function(){
  var n = 0, d = this.duration;
  progI = setInterval(function(){
    if(n < d){
      n = 0;
      for(var i=0,b=vid.buffered,p,l=b.length; i<l; i++){
        n += (b.end(i)-b.start(i))/d;
      }
      p = Math.round(n*100);
      if(p === 100)n = d;
      prog.value = p; loaded.innerHTML = p+'&#037;';
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(progI); progI = undefined;
    }
  }, 500);
}
vid.src = 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px; text-align:center;
}
#vid,#prog{
  display:block; width:400px; margin:0 auto;
}
#vid{
  height:220px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <video id='vid' type='video/mp4' controls='controls'></video>
    <progress id='prog' value='0' max='100'></progress>
    <div id='loaded'>0&#037;</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The canplaythrough doesn't mean at all that the full media has been loaded, it's just that the browser thinks it will be able to play through continuously while still fetching. If you have a correct conection and are playing a 10Hours SD video this event will fire almost immediately, even though of course it won't have loaded all the file, it's just that the browser thinks that with the average download speed it got during the metadata fetch, it will be able to get the whole while playing in the given 10Hrs. Also, it seems you forgot to answer OP's question...

Comment: Hope I fixed it. Can't be sure since I've not used progress events with video. Please teach me!

Comment: Looking back at this question, i see the percentage given is equivalent to the player's (which is what i wanted).. Should I make this the accepted answer?

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know if you can once it's been accepted. Glad it works for you though. Don't let the Matrix get you down.